# How to align list of images in a straight line in html/css?

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ktw74hp4/embedded/result/) in which I want to **list the images in a straight line with fair amount of spacing among them** similar to the screenshot below:

[image]

The HTML code which I have used to put the list of images in a straight line is:

```
<div class="images">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/abhy97dln/stripe.png" alt="" width="120" height="20" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7013">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/8wgdkj9yj/global-franchise.png" alt="" width="120" height="20" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7019">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ros8o6ynv/intuit_v1.png" alt="" width="150" height="44" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7088">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/6rw0jodjf/Franchise_Harbor.png" alt="" width="120" height="20" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7068">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ngxgf2f4b/Intercom.png" alt="" width="120" height="20" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7070">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/qb0lshepn/Inc.png" alt="" width="120" height="20" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7071">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/6rw0jm8dn/Pay_Stand.png" alt="" width="120" height="20" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7072">
</div>
```

The **CSS codes** which I have tried (**but it didn't work**) in order to put the list of images in a straight line with fair amount of spacing are:

```
.images
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    justify-content: center;
}

.images img
{
padding-left: 2%;
padding-right: 2%;
}
```

With the above CSS codes, the images do go at the center but it seems to shrink completely.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what CSS codes I should add in the fiddle so that list of images show up in a straight line with fair amount of spacing between each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have edit your fiddle

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.images img {
  width: 5rem;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="images">
<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/abhy97dln/stripe.png" alt=""  class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7013">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/8wgdkj9yj/global-franchise.png" alt=""class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7019">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ros8o6ynv/intuit_v1.png" alt="" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7088">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/6rw0jodjf/Franchise_Harbor.png" alt=""  class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7068">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/ngxgf2f4b/Intercom.png" alt="" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7070">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/qb0lshepn/Inc.png" alt=""  class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7071">

<img src="https://s7.postimg.cc/6rw0jm8dn/Pay_Stand.png" alt="" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-7072">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks very good. I have one more question. `Franchise Harbor and Intercom images` seems to completely shrink. Is there any way I can fix that ? All other images looks very good.

Comment: you can style the images instead of `width:5rem` and `height:auto` you can change it to  `height: 2.5rem` and `width: auto`

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have a similar [question](https://jsfiddle.net/nepgqcjL/4/embedded/result/). In it, the images are present inside the square. In this case what changes I should do in the CSS so that text come towards at the bottom and images stay at the place where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement these modifications into your code which works for me. *vw* means **viewport-width**

set `width="90vw"` for every images  in your html file and change following into your css.

```
.images img
{
padding-left: 1vw;
padding-right: 1vw;
}
```